# How to pass Variable One page to another in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, get

I have created dynamic button and i need to pass the button ID to another page when my button is clicked. I have pass it but it didn't work

Please give any solution

Here is my code for `dash.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();
function dash () {
    include 'config.php';

    $sql = "SELECT RoomNumber FROM roommaster ";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        $str = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            // generate array from comma delimited list.
            $rooms = explode(',', $row['RoomNumber']);
            //create the dynamic button and set the value.
            foreach ($rooms as $v) {
                $str .= "<a href = 'booking.php'?btn='btn'><input type='button' name='b1' id='btn' value='" . $v . "' /></a>";
            }
        }

        return $str;
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
    }
    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

Here is my `booking.php` page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $btn = $_POST['btn'];
    echo $btn;
}

$sql = "SELECT RoomNumber FROM roommaster where RoomId=' " . $_GET['btn'] . " '";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $RoomNumber = $row['RoomNumber'];
            // $RoomType=$row['RoomType'];
            // $Location=$row['Location'];
            // $ChargesPerDay=$row['ChargesPerDay'];
        }

        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Customer book Form</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/book.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</style> 
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/book1.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="head" id="link">
      <div class="panel panel-primary" style="margin:20px;">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <center><h3 class="panel-title"> Customer booking Form</h3></center>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form method="post" action="">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
                          <label for="roomno">Room Number*    </label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="RoomNumber"  value="<?=$_GET['btn'];?>"required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="type">Room Type*</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="RoomType" required >
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="location">Location*</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="Location" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <label for="charges">Facilities*</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="Facilities" required>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <label for="charges">ChargesPerDay*</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ChargesPerDay" required>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                         <label for="customer name">First Name*</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="FirstName" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the html form?

Comment: Try to write like this " `<a href='booking.php'?btn=$v >` and on booking.php page fetch like this `$btn = $_GET['btn'];`

Comment: where is html button?you are passing by javascript?

Comment: it gives error Undefined index: btn in C:\xampp\htdocs\roombook\booking.php on line 46
No records matching your query were found.

Comment: In you're dynamic button, you setted value to 'btn' : $str .= "<a href='booking.php'?btn='btn' > try $str .= "<a href='booking.php'?btn=$v > instead

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $_GET instead of $_POST

```
if (isset($_GET['btn'])) {
    $btn = $_GET['btn'];
    echo $btn;
}
```

Comment: Why do you propose that he uses `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: @Swellar might be because OP is generating HTML like `$str .= "<a href='booking.php'?btn='btn' ><input type='button'   name='b1' id='btn' value='".$v."' /></a>";`

Comment: @Swellar : the variable btn transit via the url, you get it with a $_GET. Using a form, you would use a $_POST

Comment: What is not working ? You should see a 'btn' in the top of you're page, which is you're echo. Your sql request should fail cause you're variable value is set to 'btn'

Comment: It's not really clear what OP uses, he has both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: Undefined index: btn in C:\xampp\htdocs\roombook\booking.php on line 46
No records matching your query were found.
this error

Comment: You have setted index value to 'btn' in your dynamic button. Try $str .= '<a href="booking.php?btn='.$v.'">'

Answer (score 1):

Try linking using a form. BUTTONID should be the value to pass. $str should be:

```
<form action='booking.php' method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' value='BUTTONID' name='bttn'>
  <input type='submit' value='".$v."'>
</form>
```

And then get the value of the hidden field as you already did...

```
$if (isset($_POST['bttn'])) {
  $btn = $_POST['bttn'];
  echo $btn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have modified script of dash.php and booking.php files. Please copy and paste this script.

**dash.php file**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
   function dash(){

      include 'config.php';

       $sql = "SELECT  RoomNumber  FROM roommaster ";

    if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql))
    {
        $str = '';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            // generate array from comma delimited list
            $rooms = explode(',', $row['RoomNumber']);
            //create the dynamic button and set the value
            foreach ( $rooms as $v )
            {
                $str .= "<a href='booking.php'?btn="'.$v.'"><input type='button'   name='b1' id='btn' value='".$v."' /></a>";

            }

        }

        return $str;



    }



      else {

        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .mysqli_error($db);
          }


mysqli_close($db);
```

**booking.php file**

```
  $sql = "SELECT  RoomNumber FROM roommaster where RoomId=' " .$_GET['btn']." '";
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $RoomNumber=$row['RoomNumber'];
                  //$RoomType=$row['RoomType'];
                  // $Location=$row['Location'];
                  // $ChargesPerDay=$row['ChargesPerDay'];
        }

        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
}
mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: Undefined index: btn in C:\xampp\htdocs\roombook\booking.php on line 46
No records matching your query were found.
 it gives error

Comment: there are not any record of room id in database . so this message are showing in frontend. because you have write condition in booking.php file, if not any record found then show this error.

Comment: records is present

Comment: firstly check in this script <code>booking.php'?btn=RoomId</code> is passed to booking.php file or not

Comment: the value is not echo

Comment: $str .= "<a href='booking.php'?btn=$v><input type='button' name='b1' id='btn' value='".$v."' /></a>";

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$_REQUEST` by that you can get both `GET` and `POST` values.In booking.php print the array like below:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);

if (isset($_REQUEST['btn'])) {
    $btn = $_REQUEST['btn'];
    echo $btn;
}
```

Comment: did you try this? @Yogesh

Comment: if it's empty array then the values are not posting..Edit the question and add where you passing the values or HTML

Answer (score 0):

To pass little data from one page to another page use parameters in the `URL` as below is `parameter` with the `value` you want to pass to next page as:

```
<a href="anotherpage.php?parameter=value">Click Button</a>
```

Then on the *anotherpage.php* use `$_GET` to get the value passed by the `URL` as:

```
$val = isset($_GET['parameter']) ? $_GET['parameter'] : NULL;
```

Then use the `$val` for other processing. I think this may can help you to understand how to pass `data` from one page to another page simply.